# What does this manuscript say?

Tags: medieval-latin, christianity, paleography

On the Medieval Latin Wikipedia page, this image is present under Influences: Christian Latin. I can make out some of the words, but I'm not particularly good with interpreting scribes' handwriting. I decided to ask this question on the Latin StackExchange, because I believe better word-recognition would certainly help here.
[image: File:MilanBTCod470BookOfHours2FoliosAnnuncShepherdsDecortatedInit2.jpg]
I can recognize some of these words, so this is what I have so far:

> ...
>   meum in
>   ...
>   nunc
>   me
>   Sicut erat
>   ...
>   ... quod
>   ... corporis
>   ...
>   ... mater

That's seriously it. Please, help — I'm totally lost. I don't need a translation, but if any of you have the time, I'd be glad to see it. If there are shortenings or uncertain words, tell me.

Comment: I took the liberty to reformat your question a bit. Feel free to re-edit or roll back. You can change row without changing paragraph by adding two spaces at the end of a line. It's quite useful for lyrics, poetry, and such.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This comes from the Book of Hours, and is the first part of the prayers at terce.

Latin:

> **Ad tertiam**
>   Deus in adiutorium meum intende.
>   Domine ad adiuvandum me festina.
>   Gloria P[atri, et Filio: et Spiritui sancto.]
>  
>   Sicut erat [in principio, et nunc, et semper: et in saecula saeculorum, Amen. Alleluia.]
>
> **Hymnus:** 
>   Memento salutis auctor. 
>   Quod n[ost]ri quondam corporis, 
>   Ex illibata virgine 
>   Nasce[n]do, formam su[m]pseris. 
>   Maria mater grati[a]e, 
>   Mater misericordi[a]e, tu...

English:

> **At the third hour**
>   Incline unto my aid O God.
>   O Lord make haste to help me.
>   Glory be to the Father, and to the Son: and to the Holy Ghost. 
>   Even as it was in the beginning, and now, and ever: and world without end. Amen. Alleluia.
>
> **Hymn:** 
>   Be mindful, author of our health, 
>   That thou sometime didst take on thee 
>   Of a pure virgin being born, 
>   The form of our humanity. 
>   Mary that mother art of grace, 
>   Of mercy mother also art,

You can see the full prayer [here](http://www.medievalist.net/hourstxt/bvm1ter.htm).

Answer (score 6):

This is undoubtedly from a book of prayers, possibly from a form of [Breviary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Breviary).

The first half reads:

> (ad tertiam)
> Deus in adiutorium meum intende
> Domine ad adiuvandum me festina
> Gloria p.
> sicut erat

The Gloria Patri is a very common prayer, so only the first words of each sentence are written. The full prayer is:

> Gloria Patri et Filio et Spiritui Sancto
> Sicut erat in principio et nunc et semper et in saecula saeculorum. Amen

Both *Deus in adiutorium* and *Gloria Patri* are common building blocks of longer prayers, as in the Roman breviary.

What is written in red are [rubrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubric): liturgical instructions to the readers rather than part of the prayers. The first rubric reads *ad tertiam* which is one of the *hours* in which the praying of the breviary is usually divided.

The second half is part of a hymn, [*Memento salutis Auctor*](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/BVM/MementoSA.html) (English translation in the linked page):

> MEMENTO, salutis Auctor, 
> quod nostri quondam corporis,
>   ex illibata Virgine
> nascendo, formam sumpseris. 
>   Maria, mater gratiae,
>   mater misericordiae,

**Update:** *pulling the thread* in Wikipedia I got to [another article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Hours_(Milan,_Biblioteca_Trivulziana,_Cod._470)) using the image giving a deeper description.

The book is indeed a Book of the Hours (breviary) known for its inventory name **Milan, Biblioteca Trivulziana, Codex 470**. The picture on the left is represents the annunciation to the shepherds (right after Jesus was born, cf. the [Gospel of Luke, ch. 2](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_nt_evang-lucam_lt.html#2).)

Comment: Nice job getting there so quickly! You're correct at that the first rubric reads *ad tertiam*.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the ʒ-like character in what seems to be _ad tertiãʒ_

Comment: @Rafael Take a look at pg. 22 (&sect;4.281) of [this book on Latin paleography](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/1821/47cappelli.pdf): "When the 3-mark occurs at the end of a word and is preceded by the vowel a, e, or u, it generally does not stand for -us or -et, but rather for m." Perhaps it is considered a flourish, since the rest of the work either uses a typical m or a bar over the preceding vowel.

Comment: @brianpck So the second rubric reads _hymnus_? Does the symbol that resembles a v stand for h or y?

Comment: @Rafael I think in context it's evident that it means *hymnus.* (In Terce, the hymn follows immediately after the introduction.) I'm not sure about the "v" character, though: perhaps it's based off the Greek upsilon and the h, being unaspirated, is skipped. That's just speculation, though

Comment: @brianpck Y/V confusion is ancient (cf. *Sulla* and *Sylla* or *silva* and *sylva*), though I do not know enough about Medieval Latin to state whether that or something else is going on here.